# Gnuplot put xtics between bars

Tags: gnuplot

I need to be able to position the tic marks so that they are between the bars in the graph. 
That way it can be read that there were 2 points between 0 and 14, 0 between 15 and 30, and so on, instead of the tics centered underneath the bars. Is there any way to automatically do that based on the box width?
[image]
Here is my current script attempt:

```
set xtics out nomirror
set ytics out nomirror
set tic scale 0
set style fill solid 1.00 border 0
set offset graph 0.1, 0.05, 0.1, 0.0
set boxwidth 15 *.9
set xtics offset -(15 *.9)/2
set term png
set output "graph.png"
plot 'data.dat' using 1:2:xtic(1) with boxes
```

Here is the .dat:

```
0       2
15      0
30      0
45      0
60      1
75      1
90      33
```

**EDIT**
It appears that the following works consistently, based on the boxwidth:

```
set bwidth=15*.9
set boxwidth bwidth
set xtics out nomirror offset -bwidth/2 left
```

There still might be a better way.

Answer (score 3):

With your solution you only shift the tic labels. I would also shift the tics.

Here is my solutions:

```
set tics out nomirror
set style fill solid 1.00 noborder
set autoscale fix
set offset 5,5,5,0

# extract the first and second x-values
stats 'data.dat' using 1 every ::::1 nooutput
start = STATS_min
width = STATS_max - STATS_min

set boxwidth width *.9
set xtics start, width

set term pngcairo
set output "graph.png"

plot 'data.dat' using ($1+width/2.0):2 with boxes
```

The first and second data values are extracted automatically (requires version >= 4.6.0). These values are used to

1. Set the boxwidth
2. Set the xtics (start value and increment)
3. Shift the data points by half of the `x`-value increment.

See e.g. [Gnuplot: How to load and display single numeric value from data file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18587275/2604213) for another example for extracting data with the `stats` command. Instead of loading the data with `stats` you could of course also use

```
start = 0
width = 15
```

The result with 4.6.3 is:

[image]