# Position xtics between bars

Tags: gnuplot

I have a dataset

```
200 45000
600 260000
2000 680000
18000 2800000
```

I generated this by processing other data (set like `{(x0, y0), (x1, y1),..}`). On the first row in the first column is the low quartile of `x` and in the second column is sum of `y`s corresponding to data with `x_0 < 200`. In the second column it is similar but the first column is median and second column is the mentioned sum for `200 < x_0 <= 600`. Third is similar (just with high quartile), fourth has the maximum value of `x` in the first column.

I want to render a box plot similar to the one below but the xtics should be right between the borders of the boxes (so each box would be between two xtics). How can I do that? The manual page for "set xtics" didn't help.

[image: box plot]

This was generated by this code (few unimportant style settings not shown):

```
plot 'data/example.dat' using 1:2:xtic(1) with boxes
```

There is a related question [Gnuplot put xtics between bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797472/gnuplot-put-xtics-between-bars) but I don't think I can apply that since I want my boxes to keep their width (although I need to somehow modify it a bit so that 200 and 600 don't overlap).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `fsteps` plotting style. But, with this you need to add an additional line to get the plot right:

```
0   45000
200 45000
600 260000
2000 680000
18000 2800000
```

and plot this e.g. with

```
set xtic rotate
plot 'test.dat' using 1:2:xtic(1) with fsteps lw 3 notitle
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, I believe this is the best it can get.