# Grouping Data Sets Together + Legend

Tags: colors, gnuplot, grouping, legend

I'm unfamiliar with the terminology of what I'm trying to do (which is making it difficult to find the solution), but I think you can figure out what I'm trying to do from the inputfile. Input file is .txt that is tab separated.

```
#input file begins here

21  00  0.005   12.0    0.006621    0.35365 0.16718
22  00  0.005   14.0    0.00662 0.34899 0.17206
23  00  0.005   16.0    0.006645    0.34523 0.17739
24  00  0.005   18.0    0.006696    0.33956 0.1815
25  00  0.005   20.0    0.006755    0.33477 0.18692
26  00  0.005   22.0    0.006797    0.33084 0.19178
27  00  0.005   24.0    0.006892    0.3265  0.19683
28  00  0.005   26.0    0.006965    0.32093 0.20256
29  00  0.005   28.0    0.007072    0.31631 0.20747

31  00  0.007   12.0    0.006158    0.38969 0.12999
32  00  0.007   14.0    0.006124    0.38578 0.13541
33  00  0.007   16.0    0.006136    0.38161 0.14018
34  00  0.007   18.0    0.006147    0.37697 0.1452
35  00  0.007   20.0    0.006193    0.37356 0.14999
36  00  0.007   22.0    0.006238    0.3673  0.15499
37  00  0.007   24.0    0.006276    0.36387 0.16037
38  00  0.007   26.0    0.00634 0.35855 0.16595
39  00  0.007   28.0    0.006417    0.35388 0.17118
40  00  0.007   30.0    0.006497    0.34844 0.17673
```

I would like to differentiate between these two blocks of data on the graph. The graph will be a 2D plot, with the top block's points in red and the bottom block's points in blue. The total inputfile is about 1000 lines long, with different vertical lengths; however, they are all appropriately separated with the newline character (\n).

I'm plotting columns 4 and 6 with the data set name (a.k.a. legend label) being column 3.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can address the different points:

1. Your input file indeed consists of two data blocks, which can be selected with `every` for plotting: `every :::0::0` selects only the first block, see the documentation or `help every`.
2. To use a red line color, just use e.g.

   ```
   plot 'file.txt' linecolor rgb 'red'
   ```
3. To select columns 4 and 6 for plotting, use `using 4:6`.
4. Using the values of the third columns as key labels is not straightforward. If you know that it is a numerical value, than you can use the `stats` command to extract these single values (see e.g. [Gnuplot: How to load and display single numeric value from data file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18587275/2604213)):

   ```
   stats 'file.txt' using 3 every :::0::0 nooutput
   key1 = sprintf('%.3f', STATS_max)
   stats 'file.txt' using 3 every :::1::1 nooutput
   key2 = sprintf('%.3f', STATS_max)
   ```

   If the column can also contain other values, or you want to maintain this same formatting, you need an external tool to extract the values for the title:

   ```
   key1 = system('head -1 file.txt | cut -f 3')
   key2 = system('tail -1 file.txt | cut -f 3')
   ```

So, alltoghether you script may look like the following:

```
stats 'file.txt' using 3 every :::0::0 nooutput
key1 = sprintf('%.3f', STATS_max)
stats 'file.txt' using 3 every :::1::1 nooutput
key2 = sprintf('%.3f', STATS_max)

plot 'file.txt' using 4:6 every :::0::0 linecolor rgb 'red' title key1,\
     ''         using 4:6 every :::1::1 linecolor rgb 'blue' title key2
```