# Gnuplot, how plot the month in a title or legend?

Tags: date, gnuplot, title, legend

have a new problem. Can someone help me with this?

A part of my datafile is

```
06-07-2013,13461,0,7464,0,  
07-07-2013,14494,0,5584,0,  
08-07-2013,149,13394,3412,2471,  
09-07-2013,295,14058,3005,3201,  
10-07-2013,194,8308,3264,4026,  
11-07-2013,14,4597,3162,1945,  
12-07-2013,113,4447,3009,2268,
```

And want to have the name of the
month and the year (in this case july 2013) in the legend or the title of the plot. How can I get first the month(value) out of the datafile and second make a text of it?

**Woow**, it is a beauty and almost perfect, look to the circle in the plot.
The Year is some late (lol).

http://ccvd.eu/downloads/Jul.png

**I got him**, the tricker was fmt = '%d-%m-%**Y**' in place of fmt = '%d-%m-%**y**'

http://ccvd.eu/downloads/Jul.png

Thank you so much!! I was for more then a day looking for the solution and now . . . YES.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, to extract a certain value from a data file, you can use the `stats` command like shown in [Gnuplot: How to load and display single numeric value from data file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18587275/2604213) (requires at least version 4.6.0).

But `stats` does not work directly with time data using `set xdata time`, you need a little trick. In the `using` statement you must access the first column as string and format it to a time stamp with `strptime`.

After that you can format this time stamp with `strftime` and put it in the title or the legend:

```
stats 'file.txt' using (strptime('%d-%m-%Y', stringcolumn(1))) every ::0::0
set title strftime('%B %Y', STATS_max)
```

Only after calling `stats` you can switch to time data with `set xdata time`.

So a more complete script could look like

```
set datafile separator ','
fmt = '%d-%m-%Y'
file = 'file.txt'

stats file using (strptime(fmt, stringcolumn(1))) every ::0::0 nooutput
date = strftime('%B %Y', STATS_max)

set title 'Data of '.date
set timefmt fmt
set xdata time
plot file using 1:2 title 'again '.date
```