# gnuplot: access a value from a file and plot that value against a column

Tags: gnuplot

I have 2 questions to do with gnuplot:

1. How can I access a specific value from a data file?
2. Can I plot that value against a column?

I have the following script:

```
plot for [iter=0:3:1] path_to_data using 1:(column(iter))
```

I would like to plot additional lines on this graph, based on values stored in path_to_expt.

The problem is that I want to plot an x value from one file (path_to_data: column(1)) against a constant y value from another file (path_to_expt).  Is this possible?

I'm not sure of the syntax to access a cell from a file but the y value is stored at: path_to_expt[row(iter), column(1)].

Can I set a variable (expt_value) inside the above loop, equal to the y value, and plot it against path_to_sim[column(1)] as follows:

```
plot for [iter=0:3:1] path_to_data using 1:(column(iter)) , \
expt_value = path_to_expt[row(iter), column(1)] , \
path_to_sim using 1:expt_value
```

I tried this but my syntax is wrong and I can't find how to access a single value from a file.  I don't know if I'll be able to plot a single value against a column but, if not, perhaps I could make a column of constant values to do this.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: There are several questions on SO about how to extract single values from a data file, e.g. [Gnuplot: How to load and display single numeric value from data file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18583180/2604213).

Comment: Very helpful,comment!